# Nested flexbox column inside row, with full height children

Tags: css, flexbox

I trying to make a tree of boxes with nested flexboxes.
I made a demo: http://jsbin.com/girucimizu/edit?html,css,output

The outer container has a `flex-direction` of `row`, the inner containers have `column`.

I also made an image to visualize my goal:

[image]

What I get is on the left side, what I need is on the right.
I want to spread the boxes evenly in the vertical direction.

I tried applying CSS I found in other threads, but none of them worked, like:

```
.stage {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a width to the stage div equal to the div widths + margin and the `justify-content:space-aound` on the `stage` divs

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.stage {
  display: flex;
  width: 52px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Why the width is required?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure. I'll have to look further.